# c# How to send a filestream still being written and keep sending until the end of the creation

Tags: c#, rest, io, stream, download

I have a Restful web service containing a method that returns a stream, and calling this method results on downloading the file associated to the stream.

Now, for performances purpose, I need this file to be downloaded while it's still being created. 
Here is the actual code of the method :

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "SendFileStream/")]
    public Stream SendFileStream()
    {
        //This thread generates a big file
        FileCreatorThread fileCreator = new FileCreatorThread();
        Thread fileCreatorThread = new Thread(fileCreator.CreateFile);
        fileCreatorThread.Start();
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.Expires, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"));
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "multipart/related";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write);
        return fs;
    }
```

This method works great, the file is downloadable while being created without throwing an IOException.
But the problem is that the download is faster than the creation and it stops as soon as it reaches the end of the stream without downloading the part that still has to be created.

So my question is, is there a way to keep the download pending until the end of the creation of the file (assuming we don't know in advance the final length of this file) without the need of a second method to check if the size of the file downloaded is the same has the length of the actual file and a method to restart the download until it's completed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: for those who wonder how it is possible to have access to a file in read and write with two different threads, here is the code of the thread generating the file.

```
    public class FileCreatorThread
    {
        public void CreateFile()
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("New line number " + i);
                writer.Flush();
                //Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Solution :**
If finaly found a solution to my problem, mainly based on these two pages :

- [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14998117-6fb8-47af-8d61-77f434b380a0/help-how-to-readwrite-a-text-file-at-the-same-time)
- [and this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

First of all I enabled the streaming in the web service.
Here's a code snipet from the web.config file, for more information see the links above

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpsStream" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>        
  </webHttpBinding>            
</bindings>
```

Secondly, I created a custom stream with an overload of the read() method that chekcs if the end of the stream has been rechaed and if so, waits a few milliseconds and retries the read() to make sure this is really the end of the file.

Here is the code of the custom stream :

```
public class BigFileStream : Stream
    {
        FileStream inStream;
        FileStream testStream;
        String filePath;

        internal BigFileStream(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
            inStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write);
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return inStream.CanRead; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            throw new Exception("This stream does not support writing.");
        }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { throw new Exception("This stream does not support the Length property."); }
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get
            {
                return inStream.Position;
            }
            set
            {
                throw new Exception("This stream does not support setting the Position property.");
            }
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int countRead = inStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            if (countRead != 0)
            {
                return countRead;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(i * 15);
                    countRead = inStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                    if (countRead != 0)
                    {
                        return countRead;
                    }
                }
                return countRead;
            }
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new Exception("This stream does not support seeking.");
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new Exception("This stream does not support setting the Length.");
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new Exception("This stream does not support writing.");
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            inStream.Close();
            base.Close();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            inStream.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

And the download method will now return this :

```
return new BigFileStream(@"c:\test.txt");
```

This is probably not the cleaner way or the most efficient way to do it so please do not hesitate to comment and suggest other solutions.

**Update 2 :**

Here is a more efficient version of the Read() method as the one I first posted could still fail if the writer takes more than 815ms to write more bytes.

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int countRead = inStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            if (countRead != 0)
            {
                return countRead;
            }
            else
            {
                Boolean fileAccessible = false;
                while (!fileAccessible)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //try to open the file in Write, if it goes in exception, that means that the file is still opened by the writer
                        testStream = new FileStream(this.filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
                        testStream.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        countRead = inStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                        if (countRead != 0)
                        {
                            return countRead;
                        }
                    }
                }
                countRead = inStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                return countRead;                  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is because you are trying to get the entire file and not segment of a file.

when a file is written from one side , the other side should request one segment at the time. lets say 4096 bytes each cycle and then create the entire file when the segments reach the file length.

I know there is a way to async webservice calls using WCF.

try to solve your problem in this direction.

if you still have a problem contact me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look this way and keep you posted either if I get it to work or if I get stuck.

Comment: I finaly managed to solve my problem, but not exactly the way you were thinking about. My solution works in two steps : 
1: Enable the streaming transport in the WCF service
2: Use a custom stream implementation with an overload of the read method that, if the end of file has been reached, waits a few milliseconds and retries the read to be sure the end of the file has really been reached, I'll update my question with my solution. 
Anyway, I'm not sure it is the really best way to do it so if you think of improvements, don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: can you post your solution here?

Comment: Here it is, please tell me what you think about it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I accept the answer even if it wasn't exactly it, it lead me to this solution.